# How to get source in response from ES while using UpdateQuery - Spring Data ElasticSearch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch to update a document in ES. How do I get the updated source back from ES as part of the response? Below is the code. The UpdateResponse seems to have only the status codes.

```
UpdateQuery updateQuery=UpdateQuery.builder(esId).withFetchSource(true).withScript(updateScript).build();
UpdateResponse updateResponse = elasticsearchTemplate.update(updateQuery, IndexCoordinates.of(indexName));
```

I am looking for equivalent of below ES API

```
GetResult result = updateResponse.getGetResult(); 
if (result.isExists()) {
    String sourceAsString = result.sourceAsString(); 
    Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = result.sourceAsMap(); 
    byte[] sourceAsBytes = result.source();
```

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code of `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.UpdateResponse`:

```java
/**
 * Response data from an update request ({@link UpdateQuery}). Currently contains only the result status value from
 * Elasticsearch. Should be extended if further information is needed.
 */
```

Nobody up to now needed and requested this. Feel free to create an issue for this at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues

Comment: Is there a way to get the client(RestHighLevelClient) from the template? Earlier versions of spring-data-elasticsearch used to have template.getClient(), but seems to be removed now. I believe it was removed to keep the layer separated/abstract, but we need this to do migration (to spring-data-elasticsearch) in stages. @P.J.Meisch

Comment: You can use `ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute()` and provide a function that will called with the current client as parameter.